# PHP spaces in HTML output when formatting code

Tags: php, html, css, whitespace

Following code will produce unwanted whitespace between icons.

```
<div>
    <img src="icon1.png" />
    <img src="icon2.png" />
</div>
```

I need to keep image tags on single lines because I have some conditions in my .phtml file, it looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <?php if ($condition1) : ?>
        <img src="icon1.png" />
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($condition2) : ?>
        <img src="icon2.png" />
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

I don't want to have all code messed up on a single line. Is there any solution for situations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `font-size:0px;` style to your `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use echo to output parts of html code. You'll get something like this

```
<div>
    <?php if (true) : 
        echo '<img src="icon2.png" />';
    endif;

    if (true) : 
        echo '<img src="icon2.png" />';
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```